# Can skin acclimatize to a the humidity level?

Tags: skin, nose

When the outdoor temperature is low, the absolute humidity is low because cold air holds less water. When the heat is turned up indoors the relative humidity decreases and during days with cold weather it can fall below 10%. [This can lead to cracked skin or lips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humidity#Human_comfort) because, I assume, dry air draws more water from the skin. So my question is, can skin acclimatize? Around here in New York, some people get cracked knuckles every winter or use moisturizer to prevent them (I use nasal saline for nosebleed prevention). If those people lived in dry climates would they have this all year around? Or does the skin (and nose) eventually acclimatize?

If I install a large humidifier in my home could that actually have adverse effects by preventing me from acclimatizing (that is, making my nose less naturally lubricated), thereby possibly causing problems when I enter other houses or buildings?

Comment: Some lifestyle things cause symptoms like high blood pressure, and thin or inflexible capillaries. for oily skin, My scalp sebaceous glands produce more or less oil depending on how often my skin is devitalized. If i shampoo every day, my scalp skin eventually makes at least 7-8 times more protective oil after one month. probably the same for the rest of the body. I didn't know you can use saline for nose. dunno if the sinuses have a lot of sebaceous glands and I don't figure you can snort almond oil. Cracked skin is protected by daily moisturizer. I had that in India doing manual laundry

Comment: @com.prehensible According to this article, the claim that scalps  produce more or less oil based on how often you shower isn't true: http://www.oprah.com/style/biggest-hair-myths-do-frequent-trims-make-hair-grow-faster/all

Comment: That's not a study, that's a self styled doctor's opinion. Doctors always disagree until they have measured the study. I'd believe that if I had an explanation of why my hair goes greasy faster when I shampoo more often... If I use soap my scalp very seldom, it becomes annoyingly oily after about 7 days. I can do that for a year. If I shampoo every day to stop it becoming greasy, my hair becomes annoyingly greasy faster and faster and eventually after about 20 hours it becomes oily versus 7 days. I've observed the effect first hand so I'd have trouble agreeing with someone who has 2nd hand.